# What is the proper to do the difference between two tuple in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

I'm looking for the proper way to do the difference between 2 tuples. For example:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (1, 0, 2)
```

**Difference expected**

```
(0, 2, 1)
```

I know I can iterate on both tuples create a new tuple then do the difference but i'm looking for something more conventional or proper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may access both indices in same iteration with help of [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) built-in. After that you simply feed generator expression to [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) to create new tuple object.

```
diff = tuple(x-y for x,y in zip(a,b))
```

Comment: This will not necessarily have the difference between the two.  It is one minus the other.  There is the possibility of having a negative number.

Comment: @zondo Who says that it is not supposed to contain negative numbers?

Comment: The definition of 'difference' says so.  It is the distance between numbers, not one number minus the other.

Comment: @zondo "Difference" is used in mathematics to mean "the result of subtracting one number from another".

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the two tuples element-wise, then you can subtract each pair in a generator expression

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> b = (1, 0, 2)
>>> tuple(i-j for i,j in zip(a,b))
(0, 2, 1)
```

Comment: This will not necessarily have the difference between the two.  It is one minus the other.  There is the possibility of having a negative number.

Comment: @zondo I did not read anything in the original question that specifies if they want the signed or unsigned difference. If they want one over the other they should make that clear in their question.

Comment: That is the meaning of difference.  It is the distance between two numbers, not one number minus the other.

Comment: @zondo A "difference" is the result of subtracting two numbers, the same way "sum" is the result of addition, "quotient" is the result of division, and "product" is the result of multiplication. These have **nothing inherently to do with sign**, I don't know where you got the impression that difference can never be negative.

Comment: I got that impression when I did mathematics.  [Here](http://www.mathwords.com/d/difference.htm) is a definition of difference that shows you what I mean.

Comment: @zondo *["The absolute difference of two real numbers x, y is given by |x − y|, the absolute value of their difference"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_difference)* The term you are referring to is "absolute difference', without the "absolute" qualifier the term difference may be negative.

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import sub
a = (1, 2, 3)
b = (1, 0, 2)
tuple(map(sub, a, b))
```

> (0, 2, 1)